# Partitioned Index rebuild in Pl-sql block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to rebuild/unusable a partitioned index in pl-sql block. I have written in below code in pl-sql block,

```
declare     m_ErrorMsg varchar2(100);  
begin    
execute immediate
'Alter Index TCMS.TTC_PERF_IDX01 Rebuild Partition
TMP_TRN_CUSTOMER_0;';    
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  m_ErrorMsg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM(SQLCODE), 1, 200) ;      
dbms_output.put_line(m_ErrorMsg);  
end;
```

Above code is giving exception:  'ORA-14010: this physical attribute may not be specified for an index partition'.

If I execute below command on Command Promt then it's working,

```
Alter Index TCMS.TTC_PERF_IDX01 Rebuild Partition TMP_TRN_CUSTOMER_0;
```

Please suggest me correct way to write it in plsql bloc.

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of your string.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I suggest that you post your comment as an answer. Seems that the semicolon is clearly the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you cannot use `;` with execute immediate clause.
your statment should be:

```
execute immediate 'Alter Index TCMS.TTC_PERF_IDX01 Rebuild Partition TMP_TRN_CUSTOMER_0';
```